# $\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{3}{1-x^{1/2}} - \frac{3}{1-x^{1/3}}$ - my answer is wrong (why?)

Tags: real-analysis

Need to find

$$\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{3}{1-x^{1/2}} - \frac{3}{1-x^{1/3}}$$

One thing I use is

$$\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{x^{1/m}-1}{x^{1/n} - 1} = n/m$$

$$ \lim_{x \to 1}\frac{3}{1-x^{1/2}} - \frac{3}{1-x^{1/3}} = 3\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{x^{1/2} - x^{1/3}}{(1-x^{1/2})((1-x^{1/3})} = 3\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{x^{2/3} (x^{1/6}-1)^2 - 2x^{1/3}+2x^{5/12}}{(1-x^{1/2})((1-x^{1/3})}= 3\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{x^{1/3} (x^{1/6}-1)^2  }{(1-x^{1/2})((1-x^{1/3})} + \frac{2x^{8/12}(x^{1/12} - 1)^2+4x^{5/24}-4x^{4/24}}{(1-x^{1/2})((1-x^{1/3})}  + ... = 3*(1/6 + 2*(3/12*2/12) + 4*(3/24*2/24)... = 3(1/6 + 1/12 + 1/24+...) = 3(\frac{1/6}{1-1/2}) = 1 $$

Answer in my book is 1/2.

**Important note** I'm in the part of book where integration and differntiation is not covered.

Comment: [WolframAlpha says the limit does not exist](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+x-%3E1+(3%2F(1-x%5E(1%2F2))+-+3%2F(1-x%5E(1%2F3))))

Comment: @AdamFrancey, I don't think that my book can be this wrong. Besides, you can check the logic of my solution, it seems pretty legit for me

Comment: Your book can be wrong, every book has errata. I don't understand the logic of your solution. Where are you using the rule you stated?

Comment: $\frac{x^{2/3} (x^{1/6}-1)^2}{(1-x^{1/2})((1-x^{1/3})} = (2/6)*(3/6)$

Comment: @JoeHalfFace You error should be in line $7$ with $\frac{5}{12}?$.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam I have $x^{1/2} - x^{1/3}$, as I need to get rid of both divisors, this should be in square, so I plus $(2x^{1/3} - 2x^{1/4}*x^{1/6})$ and then minus same thing, having square to obtain first term (1/6) and as in expanding this in infinity every power is smaller than previous, it forms decreasing geometric progression

Comment: @AbdallahHammam, line 7 isn't the line before `Answer in my book is 1/2`?

Comment: @JoeHalfFace The numerator containing exponent $\frac{5}{12}$ is obviously wrong.

Comment: $ x^{1/4) - x^{1/6})^2 = x^{1/2} - 2x^{1/4+1/6} + x^{1/3} = x^{1/2} - 2x^{3/12 + 2/12} + x^{1/3} $, so $ x^{1/2} - x^{1/3} = (x^{1/4) - x^{1/6})^2 + 2x^{5/12} - 2x^{1/3} $. Sorry, can you please point what exactly is wrong here?

Comment: @JoeHalfFace How could you be sure it's a geometric series ?

Comment: @AbdallahHammam, formula is clearly $\frac{2^k *6}{(2^k*6)^2} = \frac{1}{6 *2^k}$

Comment: @JoeHalfFace Here is a second method with the same result.

Comment: it is not harmonic series, it is $1/6(\sum_{0}^{n}\frac{1}{2^n})$, as I pointed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put $$t=x^{\frac{1}{6}}.$$

we compute

$$\lim_{t\to 1}\frac{3}{1-t}\left(\frac{1}{1+t+t^2}-\frac{1}{1+t}\right)$$

$$=\lim_{t\to 1}\left(\frac{1}{1-t}\right)\frac{-1}{2}$$

$=+\infty$ at $1^+$  and $-\infty$ at $1^-$.

Comment: I don't think that you are right as I said that answer is my book is 1/2

Comment: I was also thinking about this question and I come to the same conclusion.

Comment: @Abdallah  Do you mind if I edit, only to make the parentheses prettier? I'll go ahead an edit, and if you don't like the edit, simply roll-back to your last edit.

Comment: You didn't answer most important question, where is exact mistake

Comment: @JoeHalfFace Things are all right now.goodnight.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely there was a typo, and the intended problem was

$$\lim_{x\to1}\left({3\over1-x^{1/2}}-{2\over1-x^{1/3}} \right)$$

In general, if you are taking a limit of ${A\over1-x^{1/2}}-{B\over1-x^{1/3}}$, Abdallah Hammam's trick of letting $x=t^6$ is a good way to go:

$${A\over1-x^{1/2}}-{B\over1-x^{1/3}}={A\over1-t^3}-{B\over1-t^2}={1\over1-t}\left({A\over1+t+t^2}-{B\over1+t} \right)={(A-B)+(A-B)t-Bt^2\over(1-t)(1+t+t^2)(1+t)}$$

Since there is a $1-t$ in the denominator, you need for the numerator to go to $0$ as $t$ goes to $1$ in order for the limit to exist.  That is, you need

$$(A-B)+(A-B)-B=0$$

which is to say, you need $2A=3B$ in order to have a limit.  If, indeed, the problem meant to have $A=3$ and $B=2$ (instead of $A=B=3$), the last line is

$${1+t-2t^2\over(1-t)(1+t+t^2)(1+t)}={(1-t)(1+2t)\over(1-t)(1+t+t^2)(1+t)}={1+2t\over(1+t+t^2)(1+t)}$$

which tends to $3/(3\cdot2)=1/2$ as $t\to1$.

Answer (score 0):

Put $$t=x-1.$$

then

$$x^\frac12=(1+t)^\frac12$$

$$=1+\frac12 t(1+\epsilon(t))$$

and

$$x^\frac13=(1+t)^\frac13$$

$$=1+\frac13t(1+\epsilon(t))$$

thus, you compute

$$3\lim_{t\to 0}\frac1t(3-2)$$

$$=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac3t$$

$=+\infty $ at $t\to 0^+$ or $x\to 1^+$

and

$-\infty$ at $t\to 0^-$ or $x\to 1^-$.